# How can I use RTMPDump from a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, dll, rtmp

I need to use RTMP for a client library in C++ (I have choosen C++ because I need [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/) too).

The only thing that I have found is this: [RTMPDump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/)

The main problem is that it only gives you the a .dll file. I have tried to make the `.lib` file (doing this: ["Create .lib file from .dll"](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/)) and added to my Visual Studio project, but it doesn't seem to work (the `#include <librtmp/rtmp.h>` gives me a "No such file" error).

How can I get this to compile?

Comment: You can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` at runtime instead of relying on an import library.

Comment: FYI: I've opened a discussion if this is an on-topic question on Meta-SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287246/is-this-an-edge-case-of-asking-for-3rd-party-resource-and-link-only-answer

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know if that's possible without having the .h files

Comment: @user3313574 There is no need for a header file.  If you have the documentation to those functions that describe the parameter types and return type, plus the calling convention, then you just declare a function pointer with this information.  A header file is not magic -- all it does is describe the function in terms of those 3 things I mentioned.  You just need to get the info, and describe the function yourself.

Comment: @user3313574 Just to clarify, if the library uses structs or other types that you have to access, then yes, it would be advantageous to use the header file so you get those definitions.  But for function declarations,  you don't really need the header files, just the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably downloaded the prebuilt binary. You need the source which includes librtmp library.http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/download/rtmpdump-2.2-windows.zip

Comment: I tried but I had some problems compiling it in Windows. I'm gonna try again. And sorry for the mistaken title and awful writing I was in a hurry!

Comment: I finally did it. Just used [this](https://github.com/ValYouW/rtmpdump-vs) and compiled it with mingw!